# How do I save to RFC 5785 (The folder .well-known) in Azure Blob?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I need to save the Apple-Site-Association file to the `.well-known` top level directory in Azure Blob Storage.

How can I save a file to this url?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to save the Apple-Site-Association file to the .well-known top level directory in Azure Blob Storage.

The base URI of a [blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#blob-service-concepts) includes the name of the account, the name of the container, and the name of the blob:

```
https://{storageaccount}.blob.core.windows.net/{containername}/{blobname}
```

If you specify container name with “.well-known”, which violate [naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Naming-and-Referencing-Containers--Blobs--and-Metadata#resource-names), because container names must start with a letter or number.

Answer (score 0):

I'd been searching for this answer for several years and today I finally have it...

You need to upgrade your Azure Storage account to "Data Lake Gen2" and enable "hierarchical namespace". You can then create a directory with the period character as the first character. I did this by enabling the static website and using the $web container. I had issues trying to use the $root container.

It's likely you'll need to associate your storage account with a CDN profile in Azure. This will allow for custom DNS domains with certificates, including the potential to use fully automated certificates or your own.

The whole thing seemed complex for such a simple need. I am yet to confirm the on-going cost of this provision.